# Round rectangles in website

Tags: html, expression-web

I'm working on a web site with Expression Web. I came across this website http://www.ecodetox.ca and what I really liked was how everything seemed to be in round rectangles. I also noticed the background had a drop shadow. I'm wondering how I could  achieve this type of effect in expression web without using loads of images from Photoshop. Thanks

Comment: Flagged. This should be moved to doctype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those rounded corners *are* images :

http://www.ecodetox.ca/images/middle-accueil/middle_01.jpg 
http://www.ecodetox.ca/images/menu/menu_01.jpg

The methods for doing this are numerous and will depend on the actual design you want for your site. You will need familiarity with CSS and HTML and once you're comfortable you can check out the [myriad tutorials online](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGIE_en___US324&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rounded+corners+with+css)